# Java multithread visibility?

Tags: java, multithreading

i have read in a book saying that because of compiler optimization, code execution might be reordered to cause the ReaderThread be in infinite loop. How is that possible?

```
public class NoVisibility {
private static boolean ready;
private static int number;
private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (!ready)
            Thread.yield();
        System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: have you tried running above code? it is not going in infinite loop when I ran it in Eclipse with JRE-8

Comment: @AADTechnical - That doesn't prove anything.  The bottom line is that the JLS *permits* that code to result in an infinite loop.  See my answer.

Comment: @AADTechnical yes I ran on my desktop PC with 5 ReaderThreads, they executed perfectly (printing 42). But it depends on compiler settting and CPU I suppose. This is an example in the book Java Concurrency in Action.

Comment: @StephenC yes, agree. Is there a setup(JRE/IDE) on which we can make above code run into infinite loop?

Comment: I don't know .....

Comment: I've seen it happen on production code, fairly regularly (approximately once every 100 runs or so), on a batch program that was sharing a non concurrent map accross threads (through a ThreadLocal's default value). The batch's threads were spawned before the default map was properly set up by writes from the main thread (therefore, there was no "happens before" relationships established) and those writes were not being seen by other threads. It was an up-to-date Oracle JDK 8 running an up to date RHEL on Intel x64. It does happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is that possible?

Code reordering is possible (in general) because the Java Language Specification (JLS) says it is possible.  However, reordering is (probably) not going to be the problem here.  Rather, an infinite loop is likely to be due to hardware memory cache behavior.

In this case, there is nothing in the JLS that *requires* the writes to the variables made by the `main` method to be visible to the child thread.  The technical explanation is that there is no *happens-before* chain linking the writes to the (subsequent) reads.  Without the crucial *happens-before* chain, visibility is not guaranteed.

Note that, whether there is actually an infinite loop here will depend on all sorts of factors.  The point is that it is a possibility given the way the example code is written.

Comment: thank you, Stephen. So does it mean the child thread examines a copy or  cache of the variable "ready" so the change by main thread is not visible? or else it's not possible the child thread will result in infinite loop. Just curious.

Comment: That is one possibility.  Another is that the main thread doesn't flush the write.  And there is no theoretical reason that there couldn't be other explanations on other hardware architectures.

Comment: The correct way to understand this is to think in terms of the H-B relationships.  The cache flushes / memory barriers / whatever are just mechanisms that implement the required behavior in an executing program on certain hardware.

Answer (score -1):

it is caused by CPU cache maybe. The ReaderThread may see outdated value of the "ready" variable, so it may not break out the while loop. The outdated "ready" value is called a stale data.

Comment: why down vote? this is the explanation written in Java Concurrency in Action book.